Amazon SP-API, cannot get RDT token, saying Access token is missing
I'm trying to get Amazon RDT token but keeps getting the error:

"Access token is missing in the request header",

but the access token was already added in the request header, see below. Not sure where it went wrong. Please see below for request and response.
POST https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer Atza|IwEBIN5KNdjt6lc7-U9o-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

{
    "restrictedResources": [
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/vendor/directFulfillment/shipping/v1/shippingLabels/QhlJvY8lS",
            "dataElements": [
                "shippingAddress"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "details": "Access token is missing in the request header."
        }
    ]
}


Please keep in mind to not share actual access tokens

thanks DarkBee. By the time I submitted this post the token had already expired, but I've just edited it to cross it out, for good practice.

Figured it out myself - the header should be "x-amz-access-token" instead of "Authorization". ChatGPT gave me incorrect answer.
